# Changing date format using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I am getting date in `2015-10-30T05:00:00Z` format from a `SharePoint list` using rest.
Please help me to get the date in `2015-10-30` format using JavaScript.

Comment: Do you need only `2015-10-30`? Why would you want `10th` as well as `2015-10-30`

Comment: I just need 2015-10-30 this format.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

SharePoint adds a `String.format` function
so you can use:

```
String.format('{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}',new Date('2015-10-30T05:00:00Z'));
```

Note: String.format is defined in `msajaxbundle.js`, loaded even before most of the JavaScript files so safe to use without SOD requirements or anything.
It was modelled after the C# and VB implementations, 
so [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Format_Params) applies
(*for the major part; it does not do the alignment stuff as that makes no sense in HTML*)

```
String.format("{0:i}",new Date());  outputs: Wed Oct 07 2015 20:39:54 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
String.format("{0:F}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39:54
String.format("{0:f}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39
String.format("{0:D}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015
String.format("{0:s}",new Date());  outputs: 2015-10-07T20:39:54
String.format("{0:d}",new Date());  outputs: 10/07/2015
String.format("{0:dd}",new Date());  outputs: 07
String.format("{0:ddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wed
String.format("{0:dddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday
String.format("{0:m}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:M}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:MM}",new Date());  outputs: 10
String.format("{0:MMM}",new Date());  outputs: Oct
String.format("{0:MMMM}",new Date());  outputs: October
String.format("{0:Y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:yy}",new Date());  outputs: 15
String.format("{0:yyyy}",new Date());  outputs: 2015
String.format("{0:gg}",new Date());  outputs: A.D.
String.format("{0:T}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39:54
String.format("{0:t}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39
String.format("{0:HH}",new Date());  outputs: 20
String.format("{0:mm}",new Date());  outputs: 39
String.format("{0:ss}",new Date());  outputs: 54
```

#### It does more then just Dates:

[MSDN String.format() Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

J5 iJS string format top20 iDate

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly suggest using the MomentJS library for all date/time work client side. Writing JavaScript functions to handle this stuff is so 2000s at this point. I load MomentJS into every client side project I do these days.

http://momentjs.com

Comment: I agree with MomentJS for anything but a few date operations. Also note SharePoint has a ``sp.datetimeutils.js`` library with some (obscure) functions; but ``GetDaysAfterToday()`` is a real goodie

Comment: As always it depends what you're trying to do, momentjs is 12.4k gzipped, if you're displaying one date in ISO format with the time chopped off it's probably overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Store the value retrieved from REST call in a variable and use JavaScript slice method to get the date part. Example:

```
var x = "2015-10-30T05:00:00Z";
var y = x.slice(0,10);
alert(y);
```

Comment: Absolute positioning and String operations on Dates..  Never a good match. If a system outputs january 1st as 2016-1-1T05:00:00Z .....

Comment: I believe the date retrieved from SharePoint Date fields will always be in the form mm and dd.

Comment: Sure.. SharePoint does.. but what happens if a future Developer (*its allways humans causing problems*) rewrites part of the script and expects Dates are handled as Dates. Nothing wrong with treating Dates as Strings... *as long as one is aware of potential pittfalls*

Comment: I agree on that. Your way of doing it is a clean way.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a provider hosted app (or working with non .NET folks) you may want to use plain old Javascript; here is a technique that doesn't rely on string manipulation, if you're worried about that:

```
function datetoISODate(dateObj) {
    return dateObj.getFullYear() + "-" + (dateObj.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + dateObj.getDate();
}
```

Then you can pass in a new `Date` object created with your JSON return values, calling the function like `datetoISODate(new Date("2015-10-30T05:00:00Z"))`

Note that `Date.prototype.getMonth` is 0 based, (January => 0, February =>1, ...) so you need to add 1 back to get the format you're expecting.