# How to restrict date(Created) field to display only date and time?

Tags: client-object-model, date-time

How to restrict the date field(Created) to show only date and time instead of `Fri Apr 15 2016 16:06:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`?

I do not want to show GMT and so on. The below is my code.

```
function onQuerySucceededResp(sender, args) {    

    var listItemEnumeratorResp = collListItemResp.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumeratorResp.moveNext()) {
        var oListItemResp = listItemEnumeratorResp.get_current();
             var regX = "/(<([^>]+)>)/ig";

                    responseItems +=" <tr><td>"+oListItemResp.get_item('Author').get_lookupValue()+"</td>";
                    responseItems +="<td>"+oListItemResp.get_item('Respond_x0020_Description').replace(regX, "").substring(0, 150);+"</td>";
                    responseItems +="<td>"+oListItemResp.get_item('Created')+"</td>";
                    responseItems +="<td><a  href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='openInDialog("+oListItemResp.get_item('ID')+");'><font color='black'>View Details</font></span></a></td></tr>";           

    }
responseItems +="</table>";
    $("#divResponses").empty().append(responseItems);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the return object into a JavaScript date object as below

```
var created = new Date(olistitem.get_item(...));
```

Now you can use Date functions to create string of your desirable format.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date you get into js Date object:

```
var date = new Date(oListItemResp.get_item('Created'));
```

And then specify your own format as you want using [js Date methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), for example:

```
var yourDate = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618241/javascript-sharepoint-date-column-format)

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoints own formatting function:

```
String.format("{0:d}",new Date(oListItemResp.get_item('Created')))
```

For all formatting options, see:
[Changing date format using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript/160808#160808)