# Showing the current date in a text line on a page

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server

I made a report page for our call desk.
The page will be printed and be used by management.
So preferably i have in the page on top inside a text field a script snippet to shown the date as when this page was printed.
So i get something like

**Ticket system report of 4/12/2016**  (or some other day format).

I tried the code below as script content, but it doesn't seam to work.
It was originally written for 2010, and i am using SharePoint 2013 so maybe i need a different script.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function strpad00(s) {

        s = s + '';

        if (s.length === 1) s = '0' + s;

        return s;

    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var weekday = new Array(7);

        weekday[0] = "Sunday";

        weekday[1] = "Monday";

        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";

        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";

        weekday[4] = "Thursday";

        weekday[5] = "Friday";

        weekday[6] = "Saturday";

        var now = new Date();

        var n = weekday[now.getDay()];

        var currentDate = now.getFullYear() + "/" + strpad00(now.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + strpad00(now.getDate());

        $('.s4-pagedescription').append("<div style='float:right'>" + n + "," + currentDate + "</div>");

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have configured JQuery libraries in your SharePoint instance.

Second, the date is getting appended to an element with style `s4-pagedescription`.. Since it 2013 I believe this element doesn't exists. So you can add similar element to the page

```
<div class='s4-pagedescription' />
```

If you don't want to use jQuery then change below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

To

```
window.onload = function(){
```

Then change `$('.s4-pagedescription').append("<div style='float:right'>" + n + "," + currentDate + "</div>");});` to

```
document.getElementById("s4-pagedescription").innerHTML = currentDate;
```

Also add below at the end after closing script tag..

```
<div id='s4-pagedescription' />
```

Comment: All i want is basically an inline date text.
JQuery where should i configure that (cannt this be a normap script snipped) ?

Comment: If you want to use jQuery then we need to install/upload relevant jQuery JS files.. For your requirement I think you can use plain JavaScript.

Comment: i think plain javascript might be better for me then

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: document.DOMContentLoaded is a much more accurate representation of jQuery's document.ready than window.onload.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line of JavaScript without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerHTML = String.format("{0:D}",new Date());
```

outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015  *(date of StackOverflow post linked below)*

`String.format` is provided by SharePoint

For more Date notations see: [Changing date format using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript)