# Color code due date field

Tags: javascript, jslink

I have modified the following script to display my `ReminderDate` field in red if the date is past and also the `feedback` field is `false`.

Before implementing this and because I am a novice in jslink/javascript can anyone validate this code?

```
(function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};

    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "ReminderDate": {
            "View": ColorCodeDueDate
            }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();





function ColorCodeDueDate(ctx) {

var _feedbackValue = ctx.CurrentItem.FeedbackReceived;
var dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.ReminderDate);
var now = new Date();



// if there's no due date don't render anything
if (dueDate == 'undefined' || !dueDate) {
        return '';
    }
    else if (dueDate <now && _feedbackValue == false) {  
        return "<div style='color:red'>" + dueDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') + "</div>";
    }
    else {  
        return "<div>" + dueDate.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') + "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you feel you can not validate it yourself by acutally trying it?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: +1 to @RobertLindgren 's comment -- just give it a shot and see if it works!  It's just JavaScript, you're not going to break anything.  ;)

Comment: just tried now, but the items where the _ReminderDate_ field is in the past and the _feedback_ field is false do NOT show in red.

Comment: @Dylan Cristy the FeedBackReceived is a bolean type field,  is it correct for me to use the comparison _feedbackValue == false ?

Comment: Honestly, off the top of my head I do not remember.  I would open up the developer tools for whatever browser you are using, set a breakpoint in your code, refresh the page, and when it stops on your breakpoint, inspect the `ctx.CurrentItem` object to see what that value really is and how you can work with it.  Also, at a quick glance, the way you have written your code implies that the internal name of the "feedback" field is  `feedback` - starting with a lower case "f".  Is that really the case?

Comment: That was a typo. I have corrected the pasted code. the field is actually called "FeedbackReceived"

Answer (score 2):

Use a Chrome Browser and the [Cisar Extension](http://365csi.nl/cisar) to make CSR development a breeze with Live Editing in the browser.

If you want to develop less CSR code, take a peek at [iCSR.GitHub.io](http://iCSR.GitHub.io)

You can check all available rows/fields in a displayed View by executing (in the F12 console)

```
ctx.ListData.Row.forEach((row)=>{console.dir(row)})
```

And learn all about `String.format` ([Changing date format using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript/160808#160808)) which you can also use to format any string. It will save you lines of code when you use that [Cisar Extension](http://365csi.nl/cisar)

### Update #1

Issue with CSR is that you need the fields you reference IN the View.
So you can not create a View without your `ReminderDate` and the `FeedbackReceived` fields.

**Unless..** you put your logic in a Calculated Column `Due` and display that field in the View

```
=IF(FeedbackReceived , IF(ReminderDate,ReminderDate,"") , "")
```

*the second IF is needed to catch empty dates*

You can then simplify your CSR code.

Or, when using the [iCSR.GitHub.io](http://iCSR.GitHub.io) library, have a CSR file with only:

```
iCSR.Me({
  file: "~siteCollection/Style Library/csr_due.js",
  Fields: {
    Due:{
      View:iCSR.DueDate({
        colors:['pink','lightgreen'],
        range:[0],
        colortag:'TR'
      })
    }
  }
});
```

*the hardcoded file reference is needed to make it work in MDS (Minimal Download Strategy) enabled sites*

iCSR

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked a code I am using (embedded in a JSLink) here

```
(function () {
    var statusFieldCtx = {};

    statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "ReminderDate": {
            "View": ColorCodeDueDate
            }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
})();





function ColorCodeDueDate(ctx) {



    var _feedbackValue = ctx.CurrentItem.FeedbackReceived;
    var dueDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.ReminderDate);
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(dueDate.getTime() - now.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

    var contractExpiryHTML="";
        // Return html element with appropriate color based on ....
        // You just need to add the check to feedback variable
        if(diffDays > 60){
             contractExpiryHTML= "<span style='color :#238C00'>" + ReminderDate + "</span>"; 
        }
        if(diffDays <=60 && diffDays > 30){
             contractExpiryHTML= "<span style='color :#FFB300;'>" + ReminderDate + "</span>"; 
        }
        if (diffDays <=30){
             contractExpiryHTML= "<span style='color :#ff0000;'>" + ReminderDate + "</span>"; 
        }

        if (date1 > date2){
             contractExpiryHTML= "<span style='color :#8000FF;font-style: italic;'>" + ReminderDate + "</span>";
        }

        return contractExpiryHTML;

    }
```