# RestApi Query for sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Hi I need to get all user name who is celebrating birthday today based on the value in SPS-Birthday field using Rest API?

How to achieve this?

Comment: $.ajax({  url: siteUrl  +"/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=5&selectproperties='PreferredName,WorkEmail,PictureUrl,Title,Departament,RefinableDate00,Url'&refinementfilters='RefinableDate00:datetime("2000-02-08")'",  
        headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
        
    });

Answer (score 2):

I think direct it is not possible what you will need first fetch all site users using below REST URL.

`Your Site URL + "/_api/web/siteusers"`

Then get account name for all users from above response and generate string like below:

`var targerUsers = ["i:0#.f|membership|test.onmicrosoft.com","i:0#.f|membership|dtest1.onmicrosoft.com"];`

Then pass this variable in below URL:

`http://siteurl/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='SPS-Birthday')?@v=targerUsers`

Then in response of above query result filter by your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use in conjunction with SharePoint Search REST API as below:

```
https://sitecollectionurl/_api/search/query?querytext='*'&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'&rowlimit=5&selectproperties='PreferredName,WorkEmail,PictureUrl,Title,Department,RefinableDate00,Url'&refinementfilters='RefinableDate00:datetime("2000-02-08")'
```

Here , source id = guid of the people data source

You need to map the property `SPS-Birthday` to one the Refinable properties like `RefinableDate00`. Check below image.

[image]

Once done, wait for the crawl to be completed. In SPO, it takes anything between 24 hours to 1 week ( yes 1 freaking week).

Also important thing to note, the Date is stored something like `yyyy-mm-dd`. Here, `yyyy` is always the year 2000.

So in the above query you must form a date from today and then append the year 2000 to it.

```
&refinementfilters='RefinableDate00:datetime("2000-02-08")'
```

**Update as per Danny's comment**

So today's value can be fetched as below:

```
String.format("{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}",new Date(new Date().setFullYear(2000)) );
```

Pass this value to the REST api and after that process the JSON results :)

Comment: Why? use JavaScript hacks. SharePoint provides a String.format function ``String.format("{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}",new Date());``  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript

Comment: To set to a fixed year you have to jump through an extra hoop (because Microsofts .format( ) does not accept milliseconds): ``String.format("{0:yyyy}-{0:MM}-{0:dd}",new Date(new Date().setFullYear(2000)) );``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - this is awesome ! thanks a lot. Off topic, is there any way i can pass the culture value ? I usually use `momentjs` for that, would be awesome if its doable using this way.

Comment: Dunno, [they say Its America First and The Netherlands second](http://wantstobesecond.eu/), so (I think) I only should use my own culture ... is probably somewhere in the page context info ?

Comment: hey guys, the query is throwing bad request

Comment: @sherin - the query works for me. Can you try hitting the query in your browser and check ? Ensure that `&refinementfilters='RefinableDate00:datetime("2000-02-08")'` has the correct quotes. Also note that it takes some time for the Refinable properties to get populated.