# Change date from dd-mm-yyyy to mm-yy

Tags: 2010

I am working on a tracker where i need the results in form of month and year for the entered dates. 
Eg. Input Entry date : 20-02-2017 (dd-mm-yyyy), 
  (calculated) Output expected : **Feb-17**

I use SharePoint 2010

Sundeep P

Comment: Do you want it in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, you will have to get input in mm-dd-yyyy format.

```
var Months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var dt = new Date('02-20-2017');
var newDt = Months[dt.getMonth()] + '-' + dt.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);
```

It will give your prefeerred output **Feb-17**

Comment: SharePoint has a string format function which can do this conversion in one line: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript/160808#160808

Answer (score 0):

In a Calculated Column Formula use:

```
=TEXT( [Input Entrydate] , "mmm-yyy" )
```

source:
http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Comment: Thanks Danny, it worked i only had to remove extra spaces   =TEXT([Entry Date],"mmm-yyy")