# Sharepoint 2013 - custom display form - time/date not formatted correctly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, date-time, display-form, formatting

I have an issue on my display form with formatting. I have set the language and region correctly - and chosen time and date in a friendly format. When I enter the time and date it all looks fine - but when I see it in my new custom display form it appears as below:

[image]

How may I fix this - is there a reason for this appearing the way it does in a custom form?

I want to change the xsl in SPD - I don't want to inject more script.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Other_x0020_Practioner_x0020__x0"/>
```

How do I change this?

Comment: For this you are used CQWB?

Comment: How does this work?

Answer (score 3):

The date will save in the UTC format internally and on custom forms you have to format and show.

If you are using jQuery for your custom form, you can format as follows

```
(new Date("2017-03-30T13:00:00Z")).format("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

If not jQuery, let me know which language you are using I can provide syntax for that.

To format this in XSL you can use following syntax it worked for me.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Created, 1033, 3)"/>
```

And refer below link for additional formats
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joshuag/2009/03/25/custom-date-formats-in-sharepoint-xsl/

Comment: I'm not using jquery and really want to avoid script. I have many similar scripts - I want todo this through SP Designer.

Comment: If you go the javascript route; SharePoint provides its own ``.format`` function, So no need to load a 90 KB jQuery library to format dates: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript/160808#160808

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the details of what I needed. I looked the blog post above and it hinted at the Locale format. I need a more detailed output so I thought I would post my solution.

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(@Other_x0020_MyStuff_x0020__x0),1037, 'd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss tt')"/>
```

Output example - 8/04/2017 10.24am