# SharePoint Conditional Formatting Date Column

Tags: sharepoint-server, date-time, formatting, sharepoint-list, conditional

I've been trying to create a Conditional Color column for dates that are expired.
The expired dates should be red and the dates that are not should be clear.

I tried to use the code from http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2015/03/sharepoint-2013-conditional-formatting-in-listviews

I used this code before, and it worked once I did some configuration, however, this time the code isn't working when I did the dates, here is the list below:
[image]

Can anyone help to see what's going on?

Comment: what's the type of configuration you did ? are you deactivated Minimal download strategy feature? or changed the columns orders ?

Comment: Are you saying that I should have the list as regular standard first?

Answer (score 0):

MDS will **not** be problem if you use `RegisterModuleInit`

- First of all use Chrome and the [Cisar WYSIWYG CSR editor](https://365csi.nl/cisar)
- It gives you the boilerplate code that will work fine with MDS

:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {
          Fields: {
              "<field internal name>": {
                  View: function(ctx) { 
                    <your code>
                    return <return html>;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    });
  }
  RegisterModuleInit(
    SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/myfile.js")
    , init);
  init();
});
```

---

Furthermore

- Do **not** proces Dates as Strings
- SharePoint provides a `GetDaysAfterToday`
- SharePoint provides [String.format](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript/160808#160808) method

Formatting can be as concise as:

```
          "Created": {
              View: function(ctx) { 
                var value=new Date(ctx.CurrentItem[this.Name]);
                var daysDiff=GetDaysAfterToday(value);
                var color='inherit';
                if(daysDiff<0) color='red';
                return String.format("<span style='color:{0}'>{1:d}</span>",color,value);
              }
```

---

For more Date & Code examples see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=getdaysaftertoday