# Find list count using javascript

Tags: list-view, view

I have list with multiple views , i want to add button in each view to show the total numbers assigned to the current user

is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean with assigned to ? are you have task list ? do you mean the current user the login user? please add more details to can help you faster !!

Comment: you can apply filter on the view as created by [Me]

Comment: Why a button? Better UX is to highlight the assigned-to me Items  in the current View, needs some JavaScript and the WYSIWYG CSR (Client Side Rendering) [Cisar Editor (Chrome Extension)](http://365csi.nl/cisar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are using task list or custom list, I don't think you need to use javascript to achieve your requirements also you can't add a button to each view simply as OOTB. you will need to customize it.

**So my suggestions get the total items based on the login user as the following:**

- Open your list > select your view > from the above ribbon click on modify  view.
- At filter section > select the `assigned to field equal to [me]`
  [image]
- At total section > Count with any column as you need.

[image]

**[Output]**

[image]

**Regarding other views** you can repeat the above steps,

**Regarding new views** you can create a view from existing view that has the same configuration and starts from it :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the WYSIWIG [Cisar editor](https://365csi.nl/cisar)

Create a CSR - Client Side Rendering file that highlights (green) the Items Assigned To the current user

---

#### This is all CSR code required:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function () {

  function assignedToMe(ctx){
    if (user = ctx.CurrentItem.AssignedTo[0]) {
        color = (_spPageContextInfo.userId == user.id) ? 'lightgreen' : 'inherit';
        return String.format("<span style='background:{0}'>{1}</span>", color, user.value);
    }
    return "";
  }

  function init() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      Templates: {
        Fields: {
          "AssignedTo": {
            View: assignedToMe
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(
    SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/myfile.js")
    , init);
  init();
});
```

**JavaScript Notes:**

- `user` and `color` variables are not declared, so JS *hoists* them to local variables within the function
- the `user.id` is a string, while the `userId` is Number, comparing with **==** works fine, while comparing with **===** will not
- `String.format` is provided by SharePoint SP.js code, it can do lots more
  see: [Changing date format using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript/160808#160808)

#### It gets you colors in the View

[image]

#### Notes

- you do have to add the file to the JSLink definition of every view (open Cisar in every View and link your file, Cisar creates the JSLinks for you)
- If you execute the JS file as UserCustomAction (or load it in the MasterPage), it will be applied to **every** AssignedTo field in **every** View