# SharePoint list conditional formatting - US versus UK dates

Tags: date, ctx, date-format

I've tried my best not to ask for help, but I'm stuck, even after I learned a bit of JS, MomentJS and Client Side Rendering on SP.

The code below returns undefined in date column. If you know why, please let me know.

```
// JavaScript Document
(function () {
var condFieldCtx = {};
// Define template variable  
condFieldCtx.Templates = {};
// Define your required fields and functions to call in each case.
// In our case the field is Progress
// Override Function is PatientProgressViewTemplate
condFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "Priority": {"View": PriorityFormat},
    "PercentComplete": {"View": PercentCompleteFormat},
    "b05o": {"View": CreateDateFormat}     
};
//conditional formatting for a complete row comes here
condFieldCtx.OnPostRender = [HighlightRowOverride];
// Register the template override with SP2013 
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(condFieldCtx);
})();

function CreateDateFormat(ctx)
{
var date = new Date();
var CreateDate = moment(ctx.CurrentItem.CreateDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
var now = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
//Compare and react
if(now > CreateDate)
{
return "<span><font style='background-
color:red;display:block;'>"+ctx.CurrentItem.CreateDate+"</font>";
}
else if(now == CreateDate)
{
return "<span><font style='background-
color:yellow;display:block;'>"+ctx.CurrentItem.CreateDate+"</font></span>";
}
else
{
return ctx.CurrentItem.CreateDate;
}
}
```

Everything else works fine, as you can see below on the screenshot. It's just the dates I'm struggling with.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

[image]

---

---

---

**Edit1:**

### OK, thanks to Danny, I finally got it sorted. I hope.

Below is the working code; ctx.CurrentItem.**ColumnName** reference had to be changed to the internal name **b05o**, some tweaking here and there..

```
function CreateDateFormat(ctx)
{
var CreateDate = moment(ctx.CurrentItem.b05o).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
var now = moment(date, "L", 'en-GB', true).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
//Compare and react
if(CreateDate == 'undefined' || !CreateDate)
{
return ctx.CurrentItem.b05o;
}
else if(now > CreateDate)
{
return "<span><font style='color:white;background-color:red;display:block;'>"+ctx.CurrentItem.b05o+"</font>";
}
else if(now == CreateDate)
{
return "<span><font style='background-color:yellow;display:block;'>"+ctx.CurrentItem.b05o+"</font></span>";
}
else if(now < CreateDate)
{
return "<span><font style='color:white;background-color:green;display:block;'>"+ctx.CurrentItem.b05o+"</font></span>";
}
else
{
return ctx.CurrentItem.b05o;
}
}
```

...and here's the result and working date formatting.

[image]

The only worry I have is the format of the date displayed in debugging:

[image]

The date entered in Item 6 is **31/12/2017** and as you can see it's formatted as green on the list, which is correct, but console.log shows it as **12/07/2019**.
Below, **05/06/2017** and **06/05/2017**

```
console.log(now > CreateDate);
```

is displayed as true in debugger. Possibly not a big deal, but I'm worried that something is still nor right and it might cause issues in future.

Last problem I have is when I **Stop** editing the list I get the following error:

[image]

Not sure what to do with this :]

**Edit2:**

Danny showed me great and simple way for authoring the views live, but date **31/12/2017** still seems to be causing issues. It returns invalid date, probably because 12/31/2017 is invalid.

[image]

**Edit3:**

I had to fiddle with dates a bit to get it working, and here's what I did:

```
  "b05o": {
 View: function (ctx) {
 var valueU = ctx.CurrentItem[this.Name].split("/");
 var valueY = valueU[1] + "/" + valueU[0] + "/" +valueU[2];
 var valueM = moment(valueY).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
 var valueT = new Date(valueY);
 var daysDiff = GetDaysAfterToday(valueT);
 var color = '#ff6600';            // today dark orange
 if (daysDiff > 0) color = 'green';    // future green
 if (daysDiff < 0) color = 'red';  // past red
 if (daysDiff > 0 && daysDiff < 30) color = '#ffad33'; //next 30 days turns orange
 return String.format('<span style=background:{0};color:white>{1:d}</span>',color,ctx.CurrentItem[this.Name]);
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

Comment: use ``console.log(ctx.CurrentItem)`` and you will spot your error

Comment: Thanks Danny for guiding me in the right direction. All is working now, but, two things: **1.** debugging shows me some weird things and **2.** When I stop editing the list I get TypeError. I'd appreciate if you could guide me in the correct direction on this one :) I added new info to the main post.

Comment: Your second moment function has a date variable; but where does that come from? The error could come from other SP code, check line numbers and filenames

Comment: The missing Date variable was deleted by mistake when editing post. (It's there now). There problem with date 31/12/2017 still exists though :(

Comment: What code do you log to display those incorrect dates? Must be a formatting or dateoffset issue

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I edited the original post with a new screenshot. The list shows NaN/NaN/NaN and console.log shows Invalid date in debugging.

Comment: and ``new Date(moment(ctx.CurrentItem[this.Name], "L", 'en-GB', true))`` ?

Comment: Hi Danny, no this bit of code didn't do anything actually. Momentjs loaded correctly. Even though some dates appear to be displayed correctly, the code still thinks 08/05/2017 is August 5th and hence 31/12/2017 is invalid. I'm trying to swap DD with MM or even convert the date to String and then back to Date, but so far I've had no luck :/. What is going on with them dates...

Comment: I just checked on the momentJS site, you need a lowercase L:  ``new Date(moment("5/8/2017", "l", 'en-GB', true))`` returns: ``Sat Aug 05 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)``

Comment: I had to fiddle with dates a bit to get it working. Take a look at the code above - only now it will do what I wanted it to do, I edited the post again and changed the title as well. How do I attach both moment.js and my custom.js files on one page? Can I do it via html web part?

Comment: You can add them in JSLink property of the WebPart to apply to one page, or Install the SharePoint Editor Chrome Extension, and load them both as UserCustomAction ScriptLinks, for explanation look for John Lui's blog on UserCustomActions... BTW, you should/must use the [Cisar Chrome Extension](https://365csi.nl/cisar) for CSR, it does half the work fr you, like managing JSLink for your custom.js, you still have to load momentJS yourself, Cisar does not take care of 3rd party libraries... then mark my answer so your question is marked as having an answer

Comment: Danny, I followed instructions on both SP editor and Cisar, I loaded moment.js and mycustom.js files, both successfully linked to the webpart, but when page is refreshed, the formatting isn't applied :/. Is there anything else I should know about?

Comment: F12 dev console is your friend, watch for errors there, if you don't see errors (relating to your code) your code is wrong. Paste it into another StackOverflow question, so others can help as well

Comment: Yes, F12 is obviously very helpful, and one missing curly bracket... fixed all my problems and now that everything works, I get to understand how amazing Cisar and SP Editor tools are :). My boss will love what's coming, but I'm sure I'll be back with more ideas/questions :], Thanks, Danny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, you found the issue with the internal name yourself, that is always the best way to make learning stick.

Some tips

- avoid creating new List Fields with that "easy" SharePoint UI, that's how you get those stupid weird internal names.
  Instead create new Fields in the List settings, where you specify the Internal name first (without spaces!), then rename the column to give its DisplayName (the first name will stick as Internal Name)
- Always use Chrome and the [Cisar WYSIWYG CSR editor](https://365csi.nl/cisar) when editing CSR files
- Don't hardcode fieldnames, the fieldname the function was called on is in the `this` JavaScript Scope as `this.Name`
- No need for the MomentJS library
  If you only do simple date calculations, SharePoint provides a `GetDaysAfterToday()` function
- Try to write as less repeating code as possible, keeps your code readable and easy maintainable
  The only string different in your long 3 SPAN lines is the color
- SharePoints' `String.format()` method is very helpful to include parameters in Strings
  And can format Dates to anything you want: [Changing date format using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript/160808#160808)
- The <font> tag is no longer supported in HTML5, you set the style on the parent element

---

You code becomes something like:

```
"b05o": {
    View: function (ctx) {
     var value = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem[this.Name]);
     var daysDiff = GetDaysAfterToday(value);
     var color = 'yellow';            // today
     if (daysDiff > 0) color = 'red';    // future
     if (daysDiff < 0) color = 'green';  // past
     return String.format('<span style=background:{0};color:white>{1:d}</span>',color,value);
    }
```

**notes**

- style has no double-quotes
  because DOM element attributes (without spaces) will be quoted (with ") by the browser
  so you don't have to specify them in your code (unless they have spaces)