# Using Moment to format a date from a Sharepoint list

Tags: list, javascript, date-time

Afternoon

I'm new to using Moment and need to format a date from SharePoint in JavaScript. 
The variable is `LifeCycleStart` and I don't know the right way to format it and drop in Moment. Here's what I've got:

```
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;
        var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom   
        var LifeCycleStatus = item.LifeCycleStatusValue
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description
        txtTitle = "<p>" + LifeCycleStart + "</p><p>" + LifeCycleStatus + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: what format do you want to convert your date into ?

Comment: Preferably DD-MM-YYYY

Answer (score 1):

If you have moment loaded just use moment like this:

`var LifeCycleStart = moment(item.DeviceAvailableFrom, "MM-DD-YYYY");`

You can look at more formats [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/) in the documentation. There are plenty of formats, and you probably will find what you are looking to output.

Comment: Thanks. So do I replace the current var LifeCycleStart line with the moment version? When I do that, or add the moment line as an extra the information disappears from the table?

Comment: replace what you have: `var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom `, with what I have in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in comments that you want to format date to `DD-MM-YYYY`, you dont require moment js to be loaded. SharePoint itself provides the necessary functions to format date as per your requirement.

Danny Engelman, one of the community's top contributors has provided an excellent answer at the below link:

[Changing date format using javascript](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/160808/8068)

So, for your case, you can use it as below:

```
var LifeCycleStart = String.format('{0:dd}-{0:MM}-{0:yyyy}',new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom))
```

So your overall code would be as below:

```
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;
        var LifeCycleStart = String.format('{0:dd}-{0:MM}-{0:yyyy}',new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom));
        var LifeCycleStatus = item.LifeCycleStatusValue;
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        txtTitle = "<p>" + LifeCycleStart + "</p><p>" + LifeCycleStatus + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
});
```

Based on your comments, can you try below code. I am using the `replace` method to change the string format:

```
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {  

        var tempID = item.Id;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;
        var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom.replace(/\//g, '-');
        var LifeCycleStatus = item.LifeCycleStatusValue;
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        txtTitle = "<p>" + LifeCycleStart + "</p><p>" + LifeCycleStatus + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
});
```

Comment: Cheers, now the time displays as "NaN-NaN-NaN"

Comment: can you tell me what the value is in `item.DeviceAvailableFrom` ?

Comment: Yes, it's: 11/05/2017

Comment: so you mean that in the sharepoint list item, the value is `11/05/2017` ? am i correct and you want to make it `11-05-2017` ?

Comment: Yes, and just want it to display that, all that's coming up at the moment is NaN-NaN-NaN

Comment: @Dazza - have updated answer , please check

Answer (score 0):

Load moment.js and do this:

```
var date = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;
var LifeCycleStart = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Comment: how to compare this date with todays date? if todays date is greater than datetimefield's value, i wanna delete that item. how to do this?

Comment: LifeCycleStart has the date value from a datetime field. So if you want to compare today's date with this date (LifeCycleStart), you can format today's date in the same format as "LifeCycleStart" and then simply compare.

var LifeCycleStart = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var today = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
if(today > LifeCycleStart ){
    //item deletion code goes here..
}