# REST filter today at midnight or ignore time portion

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I may be asking the wrong question here. In SharePoint I normally filter the list with **Start Date <= Today and End Date >= Today** to get a list of staff that is out today. Both dates are in Date/Time format. I'm trying to accomplish the same in REST.

**EDIT 12/12/2017**
I think the problem lies within the formatting. SharePoint adds +8 to my current time zone so when filtered for midnight, it returns the wrong items. Any workaround this?

Below is filtered for 12/12/2017 12:00 AM
[image]

---

Currently using the following to filter today:

```
var dataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AbsenceRequest')/items?$filter=((EventDate le '" + new Date().toISOString() + "') and (EndDate ge '" + new Date().toISOString() + "') and Status eq 'Approved')&$select=SDID, calDisplayFN, EventDate, EndDate, RequestType, Status, ActivityType";
```

How do I ignore the time? EventDate and EndDate are both Date/Time format or filter by midnight?

I tried but returned an error (bad request):

```
var today = new Date();
today = moment(today).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
var currentDate = today+'T00:00:00.000Z';

var dataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AbsenceRequest')/items?$filter=((EventDate le datetime '" + currentDate + "') and (EndDate ge datetime '" + currentDate + "') and Status eq 'Approved')&$select=SDID, calDisplayFN, EventDate, EndDate, RequestType, Status, ActivityType";
```

Comment: No need for the momentJS library (which BTW is slowly being replaced with [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)). ► SharePoint adds its own date formatting options see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct date format to use in REST API filtering is `YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00.0000000Z`.

```
var today = new Date();
today = moment(today).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var currentDate = today + 'T00:00:00.0000000Z';
```

or

```
var currentDate = new Date().getFullYear() + "-" + (new Date().getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (new Date().getDate()) + "T00:00:00.0000000Z";
```

**Update -** Tested the below url at my end and was able to reproduce your issue. After getting rid of the space before `datetime`. It works for me.

Make the REST API endpoint as:

```
var dataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AbsenceRequest')/items?
$select=SDID,calDisplayFN,EventDate,EndDate,RequestType,Status,ActivityType
&$filter=((EventDate le datetime'" + currentDate + "') and (EndDate ge datetime'" + currentDate + "') and (Status eq 'Approved'))"
```

Comment: It still gives me a bad request error and then freezes Edge (can't even close the tab).  I removed the "datetime" which displays the datatable but incorrect data is being filtered.  `$filter=((EventDate le '" + currentDate + "') and (EndDate ge '" + currentDate + "') and Status eq 'Approved')`  I inserted "datetime" again and got the same error and behavior.

Comment: can you check with edited code ?

Comment: I tried. Same result. when I have "datetime" in the filter -- the page displays blank datatable then a "bad request" error message.  I removed the "datetime" and gotten incorrect result. Please see the image I posted on my initial question.  I'm on SharePoint Online if it makes any difference. Thanks Gautam.

Comment: I also tried it on a browser `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/AbsenceRequest/?filter=EventDate le datetime '2017-12-13T00:00:00Z' and EndDate ge datetime '2017-12-13T00:00:00Z` and it pulled some data. I just need to figure out what app to use to read easily than using Notepad. Thanks Gautum.

Comment: hey looks like you have not tried my code completely. In my code, i have written `$select` statement first and then `$filter`. Can you do that and check ?

Comment: Yes, I tried this first `var dataUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AbsenceRequest')/items?$select=SDID, Absentee, EventDate, EndDate, RequestType, Status, ActivityType&$filter=((EventDate le datetime '" + currentDate  + "') and (EndDate ge datetime '" + currentDate + "'))";` which gave a bad request error.

Comment: ok have edited the code and got rid of extra space before `datetime`. It started working now. Notice have removed extra space and made it `datetime'"` instead of `datetime '"`. Apologies :( . Ensure that your url is as `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AbsenceRequest')/items?$select=SDID,calDisplayFN,EventDate,EndDate,RequestType,Status,ActivityType
    &$filter=((EventDate le datetime'" + currentDate + "') and (EndDate ge datetime'" + currentDate + "') and (Status eq 'Approved'))`

Comment: hey @TamrasMerin - have you tried the edited code ? did it work for you ? If yes, could you please accept it as answer ?

Comment: hi @Gautam, sorry for the delay.  I ended up using two new columns that are already set to midnight `[EventDateISO]` and `[endDateISO]`. It worked using the same filter as you suggested.