# Javascript in CSR, Slice & Substr

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering, string

I have the below function,which colors Title column in SP Online. I want to extract just the last 2 characters from "Period" and use it in the Switch case.

I tried Slice,Substr function but both didn't work. Can someone help me?

```
function PeriodView(ctx) {
var Period = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"];
switch (Period)
{
case "2017-09":
return '<b><u>' + Period + '</u></b>';
break;
case "2017-10":
return '<b><i>' + Period + '</i></b>';
break;
default:
return '<center>' + Period + '</center>';
break;
}
}
```

Comment: var Period = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"];
var slicedPeriod = Period.slice(-2);
switch (slicedPeriod)

Comment: @Christoffer This worked.

Comment: String operations on Dates will (eventually) cause headaches ... SharePoint has extra functions to deal with Dates: see: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160806/changing-date-format-using-javascript/160808#160808

Answer (score 0):

As Christoffer says, you can handle slicing like this:

```
var slicedPeriod = Period.length > 2? Period.substr(-2): Period
```

And then just continue with it in your switch.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var Period = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"]; 
var slicedPeriod = Period.slice(-2); 
switch (slicedPeriod)
```